# How to use javascript regex to match a string exactly before activating submit button

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have a angular form with a text input that requires a string to be entered in exactly like this: c, d, e, g, a, f etc...

However, as soon as one part of the input matches, the submit button activates and a user can submit the form even if I put a number or capital letter. I want to disable this and not let a user click submit unless it matches perfectly as opposed to just finding one match and activating the button. I want the regex to only allow lowercase letters that match one of the 6 above and are separated by commas.

Input text field:

```
<input type="text" name="input" ng-model="keysToPlay.text" ng-pattern="format"   required ng-trim="false" class="form-control" placeholder="c, d, e, etc...">
```

My regex is:

```
$scope.format = /^[cdefgab]{1}(, [cdefgab]{1})*/;
```

Comment: You missed ends with anchor `$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works properly:
`placeholder="((?:[ac-g], ?)+[ac-g])"`
If not let me know and I'll see if I can fix it